# Can't connect to WiFi on Ubuntu 16.04.3 after moving country

Tags: 16.04, internet

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 on a Dell laptop. I never had a problem connecting with WiFi until now. 3 months ago I moved to Greece from Ireland and have not been able to connect to any network here. My phone can connect to the network fine. Using the network tab in the top right of the screen I can edit connections, and have added the network I want to connect to, but I don't see the option to connect. WiFi and networking are enabled. Please help.

Comment: Does your network card show up still? What happens if you use `iwlist`

Comment: Kristopher, when I use «iwlist» in terminal I get a list that says «[interface]» with words such as «scanning», «frequency» and «channel» beside it. When I use «lspci | grep -i net» I get information about my network controller, «Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205». Is either of these things what you mean?